# Check duplicates in sql table and replace the duplicates ID in another table

Tags: sql

I have a table with duplicate entries (I forgot to make NAME column unique)

So I now have this Duplicate entry table called 'table 1'

```
ID   NAME   
1    John F Smith  
2    Sam  G Davies  
3    Tom  W Mack  
4    Bob  W E Jone  
5    Tom  W Mack
```

IE ID 3 and 5 are duplicates

Table 2

```
ID   NAMEID         ORDERS
1    2              item4
2    1              item5
3    4              item6
4    3              item23
5    5              item34
```

NAMEID are ID from table 1. Table 2 ID 4 and 5 I want to have NAMEID of 3 (Tom  W Mack's Orders) like so

Table 2 (correct version)

```
ID   NAMEID         ORDERS
1    2              item4
2    1              item5
3    4              item6
4    3              item23
5    3              item34
```

Is there an easy way to find and update the duplicates NAMEID in table 2 then remove the duplicates from table 1

Comment: If there are just a few duplicate records, the best procedure is to delete these manually on an individual basis

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
-- set up the environment
create table #t (ID int,  NAME  varchar(50))

insert #t values
(1,    'John F Smith'),  
(2,    'Sam  G Davies'),  
(3,    'Tom  W Mack'),
(4,    'Bob  W E Jone'),  
(5,    'Tom  W Mack') 

create table #t2 (ID int,  NAMEID int, ORDERS varchar(10))

insert #t2 values
(1,    2,              'item4'),
(2,    1,              'item5'),
(3,    4,              'item6'),
(4,    3,              'item23'),
(5,    5,              'item34')
go

-- update the referencing table first
;with x as (
    select id,
    first_value(id) over(partition by name order by id) replace_with
    from #t
),
y as (
    select #t2.nameid, x.replace_with
    FROM #t2 
    join x on #t2.nameid = x.id
    where #t2.nameid <> x.replace_with
)
update y set nameid = replace_with 

-- delete duplicates from referenced table
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn
    from #t
)
delete x where rn > 1

select * from #t
select * from #t2
```

Pls, test first for performance and validity.

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you can do is. 
You can find how many duplicate records you have. 
In Order to find duplicate records you can use.

```
SELECT  ID, NAME,COUNT(1) as CNT FROM   TABLE1 GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

This is will give you the count and you find all the duplicate records 
and delete them manually.

Don't forget to alter your table after removing all the duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the example data

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    (`ID`, `NAME`)
VALUES
    (1, 'NameA'),
    (2, 'NameB'),
    (3, 'NameA'),
    (4, 'NameC'),
    (5, 'NameB'),
    (6, 'NameD')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TableB
    (`ID`, `NAMEID`, `ORDERS`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'itemB1'),
    (2, 1, 'itemA1'),
    (3, 4, 'itemC1'),
    (4, 3, 'itemA2'),
    (5, 5, 'itemB2'),
    (5, 6, 'itemD1')
```

(makes it a bit easier to spot the duplicates and check the result)

Let's start with a simple query to get the smallest ID for a given NAME

```
SELECT
    NAME, min(ID)
FROM
    tableA
GROUP BY
    NAME
```

And the result is `[NameA,1], [NameB,2], [NameC,4], [NameD,6]`

Now if you use that as an uncorrelated subquery for a JOIN with the base table like

```
SELECT
    keep.kid, dup.id
FROM
    tableA as dup
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            NAME, min(ID) as kid
        FROM
            tableA
        GROUP BY
            NAME
    ) as keep
ON
    keep.NAME=dup.NAME
    AND keep.kid<dup.id
```

It finds all duplicates that have the same name as in the result of the subquery but a different id + it also gives you the id of the "original", i.e. the smallest id for that name.
For the example it's `[1,3], [2,5]`

Now you can use that in an UPDATE query like

```
UPDATE
    TableB as b
JOIN
    tableA as dup
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            NAME, min(ID) as kid
        FROM
            tableA
        GROUP BY
            NAME
    ) as keep
ON
    keep.NAME=dup.NAME
    AND keep.kid<dup.id
SET
    b.NAMEID=keep.kid
WHERE
    b.NAMEID=dup.id
```

And the result is

```
ID,NAMEID,ORDERS
1, 2, itemB1
2, 1, itemA1
3, 4, itemC1
4, 1, itemA2 <- now has NAMEID=1
5, 2, itemB2 <- now has NAMEID=2
5, 6, itemD1
```

To eleminate the duplicates from tableA you can use the first query again.